# Zend Studio 7.2 Not creating proper project files

Tags: php, zend-studio

I am just trying to test out the new Zend Studio 7.2, and in the beginning I was able to create proper project files just fine, but for some reason, not it doesn't want to create them I just receive empty files, plus some "error icons" on top of the files.

I have Zend Server (Community Edition) installed and trying to see if that will help the problem, but it too doesn't seem to be helping.

Things I have done to try and solve the problem:

1. Re-Install the software
2. File -> New -> New Zend Framework Project

   - Create project on local server
   - Create project in workspace
   - Create project at existing location
3. Changing the project layout from "Default project structure" to Zend Framework and Dojo structure, just to see if that would kick something into gear. But no go.

I am at a loss, I would like it if Dreamweaver was smart with Zend Framework but it isn't from what I can tell. So I want to try this.

Is there any suggestions as why this might be happening?

Comment: *(suggestion)* You might want to try the Zend Support Forums http://forums.zend.com/viewforum.php?f=59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver CS5 was my answer. Although it may not have every little trick in the book for Zend Framework, it at least has half-decent code hinting.